# Traefik - Cannot get Let's Encrypt certificate - context deadline exceeded

Tags: lets-encrypt

I got "context deadline exceeded" error while getting Lets Encrypt certificate while installing Traefik, so I cannot get the cert. Port 80 is open and not blocked by iptables or VPS provider.

Comment: This needs a lot more details. Which commands you used, what's your configuration and what was the exact output?

Comment: I use this manual https://tech.aufomm.com/traefik/ . Output is nothing in the terminal, coursor freezes - waiting. I use https://letsdebug.net to get info about the error. " Experienced error: context deadline exceeded", "A test authorization for domain.com to the Let's Encrypt staging service has revealed issues that may prevent any certificate for this domain being issued". A DNS record is fine, points to the server.

Comment: Please edit the question to include that information